# Date will not populate in form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am currently trying to put a date that I pulled from my PSQL that looks like,
2023-04-05T05:00:00.000Z, but I am wanting to place this date in my date form which has the format mm/dd/yyyy. I thought I needed to do that by doing this:

```
    const dateOfOrder = dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        year: 'numeric'
    });
```

and that does give me what I want, but when I put dateOfOrder as the value for the input form that is of type "date", nothing changes, but if the type is "text" THEN it appears. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
function JobForm({ job}) {
    const dateObj = new Date(job.date_of_order);
    const dateOfOrder = dateObj.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit',
        year: 'numeric'
    });
    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label htmlFor="TransportDate">Date</Form.Label>
                <input type="date" className="form-control" id="TransportFrom" required value={dateOfOrder}></input>
            </Form.Group>
</Form >
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The date should be entered in YYYY-MM-DD format.
Reference documentation:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-(type=date)

You can just get that format using substring and set this as value.

```
const dateOfOrder = job.date_of_order.substring(0, 10);
```